# Как оцентрировать блок

Tags: html, css

На сайте есть блок, который на разных устройствах оцентрирован по разному, т.е на моем пк он по центру, на других - нет. Как решить проблему?

```css
#SECTION_1 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  height: 700px;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  perspective-origin: 676px 624px;
  transform-origin: 676px 624px;
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  background: rgb(14, 17, 37) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
  margin: 0px -20px;
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px "roboto slab", "helvetica neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
  padding: 70px 0px;
}


/*#SECTION_1*/

#SECTION_1:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px "roboto slab", "helvetica neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#SECTION_1:after*/

#SECTION_1:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px "roboto slab", "helvetica neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#SECTION_1:before*/

#DIV_2 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  height: 1108px;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  width: 1170px;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  perspective-origin: 585px 554px;
  transform-origin: 585px 554px;
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px "roboto slab", "helvetica neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px 9px;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
  padding: 0px 350px;
  margin-top: -60px
}


/*#DIV_2*/

#DIV_2:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  clear: both;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  content: '"' '"';
  display: table;
  height: 0px;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  width: 0px;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  perspective-origin: 0px 0px;
  transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px "roboto slab", "helvetica neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#DIV_2:after*/

#DIV_2:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  content: '"' '"';
  display: table;
  height: 0px;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  width: 0px;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  perspective-origin: 0px 0px;
  transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px "roboto slab", "helvetica neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#DIV_2:before*/

#H2_3 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  height: 44px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  width: 1140px;
  column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  perspective-origin: 570px 22px;
  transform-origin: 570px 22px;
  caret-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font: normal normal 700 normal 40px / 44px montserrat, "helvetica neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px 0px 30px;
  outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
}


/*#H2_3*/

#H2_3:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  caret-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font: normal normal 700 normal 40px / 44px montserrat, "helvetica neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
}


/*#H2_3:after*/

#H2_3:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  caret-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font: normal normal 700 normal 40px / 44px montserrat, "helvetica neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
}


/*#H2_3:before*/

#DIV_4 {
  bottom: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  height: 925px;
  left: 0px;
  min-height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  width: 1220px;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  perspective-origin: 610px 462.5px;
  transform-origin: 610px 462.5px;
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px "roboto slab", "helvetica neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 75px -40px 0px;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/*#DIV_4*/

#DIV_4:after {
  bottom: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  content: '""';
  display: none;
  height: 20%;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(rgba(0, 43, 75, 0) 0%, rgb(0, 43, 75) 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px "roboto slab", "helvetica neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#DIV_4:after*/

#DIV_4:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px "roboto slab", "helvetica neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#DIV_4:before*/
```

```html
<section id="SECTION_1">
  <div id="DIV_2">

    <h2 id="H2_3">
      Roadmap
    </h2>

    <div id="DIV_4">
      <div id="DIV_5">
        <div id="DIV_6">
          <div id="DIV_7">
            <span id="SPAN_8">Q1 2018</span> <span id="SPAN_9"></span>
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_10">
            <img src="img/check.svg" alt="" id="IMG_11" />
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_12">
            <span id="SPAN_13">Establish first Crypto-Mine</span>
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_14">
            <svg id="svg_15">
                            <use id="use_16">
                            </use>
                        </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="DIV_17">
          <div id="DIV_18">
            <span id="SPAN_19">Q2/Q3 2018</span> <span id="SPAN_20"></span>
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_21">
            <img src="img/check.svg" alt="" id="IMG_22" />
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_23">
            <span id="SPAN_24">Launch Ponos-Mining Platform.<br>First dividend payouts.</span>
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_25">
            <svg id="svg_26">
                            <use id="use_27">
                            </use>
                        </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="DIV_28">
          <div id="DIV_29">
            <span id="SPAN_30">Q3/Q4 2018</span> <span id="SPAN_31"></span>
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_32">
            <img src="img/check.svg" alt="" id="IMG_33" />
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_34">
            <span id="SPAN_36">Launch Wallet platform, Vidulum.<br>



Expand total mining capacity by 25%.</span>
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_37">
            <svg id="svg_38">
                            <use id="use_39">
                            </use>
                        </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="DIV_40">
          <div id="DIV_41">
            <span id="SPAN_42">Q2/Q3 2019</span> <span id="SPAN_43"></span>
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_44">
            <img src="img/check.svg" alt="" id="IMG_45" />
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_46" style="width:300px; margin-left:-64px">
            Expand total mining capacity<br> by 50% from inception.


          </div>
          <div id="DIV_47">
            <svg id="svg_48">
                            <use id="use_49">
                            </use>
                        </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="DIV_50">
          <div id="DIV_51">
            <span id="SPAN_52">Q3/Q4 2019</span> <span id="SPAN_53"></span>
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_54">
            <img src="img/check.svg" alt="" id="IMG_55" />
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_56">
            <span id="SPAN_58">Double mining capacity from inception.<br>



Launch marketplace platform, OneMarketStreet
                          </span>
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_59">
            <svg id="svg_60">
                            <use id="use_61">
                            </use>
                        </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="DIV_62" style="margin-left:420px">
          <div id="DIV_63">
            <span id="SPAN_64" style="margin-top:-280px">Q2 2020</span> <span id="SPAN_65"></span>
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_66">
            <img src="img/check.svg" alt="" id="IMG_67" />
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_68" style="width:300px; left:-50px">Triple mining capacity from inception.
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_69">
            <svg id="svg_70">
                            <use id="use_71">
                            </use>
                        </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="DIV_72">
          <div id="DIV_73">
            <span id="SPAN_74" style="margin-top:-280px; margin-left:434px">Q3 2020</span> <span id="SPAN_75" style="margin-left:500px"></span>
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_76" style="margin-left:515px">
            <img src="img/check.svg" alt="" id="IMG_77" />
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_78" style="margin-left:434px">
            Establish VRTM's fungibility.
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_79">
            <svg id="svg_80">
                            <use id="use_81">
                            </use>
                        </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="DIV_82">
          <div id="DIV_83">
            <span id="SPAN_84" style="margin-top:-280px; margin-left:434px">FUTURE</span>
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_86" style="margin-left:515px">
            <img src="img/check.svg" alt="" id="IMG_87" />
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_88">

          </div>
          <div id="DIV_91">
            <svg id="svg_92">
                            <use id="use_93">
                            </use>
                        </svg>
          </div>
        </div>









      </div>
      <div id="DIV_240">
        <div id="DIV_241">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Какой конкретно блок?

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 div 2

Comment: @Ayurownz, ух.. Посмотрел.. У вас вёртска вышла фиксированной, всё на пикселях - это вообще не резиновый шаблон. На вашем месте я бы почитал под "адаптивный\резиновый метод вёрстки", а потом переделал всё заново.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 т.е сейчас никак не сделать?

Comment: можно, перевести в резиновую. Но я бы посоветовал почитать, чтобы потом с этим не столкнуться снова, а потом уже начать с нуля. Не так много там реализовано.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 а вы не могли бы показать, как сейчас перевести в резиновую?

Comment: Зачем плодить вопросы. На этот вопрос уже дали ответ.

Comment: @Ayurpwnz, Несмотря, что речь идет об одном конкретном блоке, я бы закрыл этот вопрос, как слишком общий...  Тут все в кучу... Надо все с нуля переписывать. Не сочти за высокомерие, но я бы тебе посоветовал научиться верстать, потом такие сложные конструкции собирать. Все в кучу...  Нет ни одного `input` или любого блока для ввода текста, зачем тут `caret-color: ;`... ???  Не стоит писать `class-Ы и ID` в верхнем регистре. Нет конечно все работает.  Попадется браузер какой-нить мобильный который не поймет и будешь искать что да как...

Comment: Не стоит использовать инлайновые стили, они же имеют приоритет, потом будешь искать где что да как...  Сомневаюсь что у кого-то возникнет желание все это переделывать.  Получиться целый курс молодого бойца, а не центрирование одного блока...